# Calculate volume of intersection two non-aligned cuboids

Tags: geometry, volume, computational-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-hulls

I'm on the lookout to finding an algorithm that calculates the volume of the intersection between two cuboids. Most answers so far assume all the axes of the two cuboids in question are nicely aligned. Not the case in my problem. See figure below

[image]

Finding out what corners of the two cuboid are in each others space is not that difficult. Also determining some boundary points on the cuboids faces shouldn't be problematic. The hard part where I get lost is to determine what kind of shape the intersection actually is and how to calculate it's volume. I think it's safe to assume the intersection will be convex. Any suggestions?

Comment: Depending on how they intersect, use planes to divide your region into more workable sub-regions. Find their volume individually and add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative approach:

Define each of your cuboids or parallelepipeds as six opposing faces.

For each face of the target convex polyhedron, define both the face plane (unit normal vector $\hat{n}$ and signed distance from origin $d$, so that point $\vec{p}$ is inside the halfspace if and only if $\hat{n}\cdot\vec{p} - d \ge 0$),  and the vertices of the face polygon $\vec{v}_i$, $i = 1 \dots N$, in counterclockwise order so that
$$\hat{n}\cdot\bigl((\vec{v}_{i-1} - \vec{v}_i) \times (\vec{v}_{i+1} - \vec{v}_i)\bigr) \gt 0 \quad \forall i$$
where the index wraps around, i.e. $\vec{v}_0 = \vec{v}_N$ and $\vec{v}_{N+1} = \vec{v}_1$.

Then, apply each halfspace $\hat{n}$, $d$ of the other convex polyhedron, cutting out the vertices $\vec{v}$ in the target polyhedron that are outside the cutting halfspace, $\hat{n}\cdot\vec{v} - d \lt 0$, one at a time.

Because you "cut" the convex polyhedron left with halfspaces, the result is either a convex polyhedron, or nothing.  Note that the centroid is always within the convex polyhedron, so the total volume can be calculated as the sum of the volumes of pyramids with the apex at the centroid, and the base the face polygon.

If the halfspace includes all existing vertices, it includes the entire polyhedron, and the halfspace has no effect.

Otherwise, the halfspace removes at least one vertex, and adds a new face.

If the halfspace removes all vertices of a face, that face is completely removed.

On each face where at least one vertex, but not all vertices, are removed by the halfspace, a section of the face polygon is replaced by a single edge, corresponding to the intersection with the face plane and the new halfspace (plane), so that all removed vertices are in the replaced segment; *and the removed vertices are continuous in the face polygon*.

So, by identifying first the vertices excluded by the halfspace, then finding the face edges between an excluded vertex and not-excluded vertex (line-plane intersection – very fast to compute), we can quickly update each partially cut face.  The added new edges across all existing faces form the new face, too.

If you describe each convex polyhedron with a data structure that contains

- All $N$ vertices $\vec{v}_i$, $i = 1 \dots N$, on the convex polyhedron
- All $F$ face unit normal vectors $\hat{n}_f$ and signed distances $d_f$ from origin, $f = 1 \dots F$
- For each face $f$, the vertices (vertex indexes) in counterclockwise order, defining the face polygon

you can quickly construct the set of edges that will be modified (for example, as triplets *from vertex*, *to vertex*, *face*), and their replacements.

---

Let $\vec{v}_k$ are the $K$ vertices of a convex polyhedron, $k = 1 \dots K$.  The centroid $\vec{C}$ is then
$$\vec{C} = \frac{1}{K} \sum_{k=1}^{K} \vec{v}_k$$

Let $\vec{p}_i$ are the $N$ vertices of one planar face of the convex polyhedron, $i = 1 \dots N$, with cyclic indexing so $\vec{p}_0 = \vec{p}_N$ and $\vec{p}_{N+1} = \vec{p}_1$.  Let $\hat{n}$ be the face plane unit normal vector, pointing inwards.  Because the polyhedron is convex, each face polygon is convex also, and therefore the face centroid $\vec{c}$ is
$$\vec{c} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \vec{p}_i$$
and the area of this face is
$$A = \frac{1}{2} \left\lVert \sum_{i=1}^{N} (\vec{p}_i - \vec{c}) \times (\vec{p}_{i+1} - \vec{c}) \right\rVert = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \left\lvert \hat{n} \cdot (\vec{p}_{i} - \vec{c}) \times (\vec{p}_{i+1} - \vec{c}) \right\rvert$$
(because each cross product summand is always $\lambda \hat{n}$, $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, by definition – otherwise the face is not planar! – and $\lambda \ge 0$ or $\lambda \le 0$ depending on whether the vertices are in counterclockwise or clockwise order in the convex planar polygon) and the volume contribution of this face is
$$V_f = \frac{A}{3} \hat{n} \cdot \left(\vec{C} - \vec{c}\right) = \frac{\hat{n} \cdot (\vec{C} - \vec{c})}{6} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \left\lvert \hat{n} \cdot (\vec{p}_{i} - \vec{c}) \times (\vec{p}_{i+1} - \vec{c}) \right\rvert$$
Summing the volume contributions of all faces yields the total volume,
$$V = \sum_{f=1}^{F} V_f$$

Answer (score 1):

The intersection of convex sets is always convex.  Divide the intersection into disjoint tetrahedra and use the well-known formula for the [volume of a tetrahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron#General_properties), given the vertices.  It seems to me that you should be able to do this by selecting any point in the interior of the intersection to be the apex of all the tetrahedra.  Then triangulate each face of the intersection.  The vertices of the triangles, together with the distinguished interior point, give all the tetrahedra.

I haven't really thought about how to program this, but it doesn't sound very hard.

Comment: It's harder than it looks :p

Comment: @hasdrubal Isn't it always?  The biggest stumbling block I see is that we have to be able to list the vertices of each face of the intersection in order.  We can find the centroid of the face, take the vector from it to any vertex as a reference $v$ and then find the cosine of the angles between $v$ and the vectors from the centroid to the other vertices.  Of course, we could translate the centroid to the origin, and rotate the plane of the face to the $xy$-plane, and look at what quadrants the vertices are in.  But there's probably an easier, standard technique in computational geometry.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. If $C_1$ and $C_2$ denote the two cuboids, you can assume for all the calculations that $C_1$ is a cube with unit sidelengths (with, at the very end, a multiplication by the 3 initial dimensions of $C_1$, in order to get the real volume).
2. Then, select a parameterization standard for $C_2$. If you choose coordinates of center + directions of axes + lengths, you will need as many as $3+2+2+3=10$ parameters for that (3 for the center, 2 for the unit vector of the first axis, 2 for the unit vector of the second axis, 0 for the third axis which is the cross product of the previous vectors ; finally, 3 for the length, width and height). Any other parameterization method will need as well $10$ parameters.
3. Use ["marching cubes"](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3410984_Brodlie_K_Improving_the_robustness_and_accuracy_of_the_marching_cubes_algorithm_for_isosurfacing_IEEE_Trans_Viz_and_Comput_Graph_91_16-29/figures?lo=1) method for taking into account the different cases of intersection that can occur.
4. Finally use, as advised by @saulspatz, a decomposition into tetrahedra whose volumes' computation is easy.